# create sequences of dates depending on another variable

Tags: r, shiny

I need some help for my work;
I have a dataset like this:

```
DATE        COD    QTA
2014-01-02   87     11
2014-01-05   87      5
2015-02-03   45      3
2015-06-21   45     92
2014-09-18   74     34
2015-04-21   74     27
```

I need to create, for eache value of the variable COD, the sequence of all dates from the min value (example: for COD 87, the min date is 2014-01-02) to the `Sys.Date()`. The final result that I would like to have is something like that:

```
DATE         COD    QTA
2014-01-02    87     11
2014-01-03    87      0
2014-01-04    87      0
2014-01-05    87      5
2014-01-06    87      0 
...           87     ... 
Sys.Date()    87      x
2015-02-03    45      3
2015-02-04    45      0
2015-02-05    45      0
...           45     ...
Sys.Date()    45      x
```

How can I do that? Thanks guys!

Comment: what did you try so far ?

Comment: not so much because I'm new with R programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `data.table` solution:

```
require(data.table)
dt<-as.data.table(df)
dt[dt[,list(DATE=seq(min(DATE),Sys.Date(),by="day")),by=COD],
      on=c("COD","DATE")][,QTA:=ifelse(is.na(QTA),0,QTA)][]
#            DATE COD QTA
#   1: 2014-01-02  87  11
#   2: 2014-01-03  87   0
#   3: 2014-01-04  87   0
#   4: 2014-01-05  87   5
#   5: 2014-01-06  87   0
#  ---                   
#2601: 2016-12-19  74   0
#2602: 2016-12-20  74   0
#2603: 2016-12-21  74   0
#2604: 2016-12-22  74   0
#2605: 2016-12-23  74   0
```

Comment: It works very well!! That's exactly what I needed...good job!!

Comment: A minor improvement: `dt[dt[, list(DATE = seq(min(DATE), Sys.Date(), by = "day")), by = COD], on = c("COD","DATE")][is.na(QTA), QTA := 0][]` (no need to use `ifelse`, you can filtter in `i` and then update by reference)

Comment: @Mig Glad it helped. Consider accepting the answer if you found it useful.